# Infinite bias for MLE

Tags: statistics

I am asked to consider a random observed variable $X$ whose distribution is known to be binomial with parameters $(n,\: k/N)$, where $n$ and $k$ are known, but $N$ is an unknown parameter strictly larger than $k$.

First, I need to find the MLE $\hat{N}$ for $N$. I've done this and got $\hat{N} = \frac{kn}{X}$. However, the next question asks me to show that $\hat{N}$ has infinite bias for any value of $n$ and $k$. What is infinite bias? I was not able to find anything online or in my notes.

I am then asked to compute the bias for the alternative estimator $\tilde{N} := \frac{k(n+1)}{X+1}$. How are you supposed to do this with the random variable in the denominator?

Comment: The bias is $E(\hat N)-N.$ Infinite bias would mean this is is infinite. Presumably has to do with that $X$ in the denominator possibly being zero.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint and some notes:***

The problem here is that the Bias you are searching is this:

$\mathbb{E}[\frac{nk}{X}-N]$

The difficulty here is to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$

Without doing a lot of calculation

1) $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{nk}{N}$

2) Via Jensen's inequality I know that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]>\mathbb{E}[X]$ and so

3) $\mathbb{E}[\frac{nk}{X}]>N$

In other words, surely the bias is always strictly $>0$. To show that it is $\infty$ you have to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$ with the definition

$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]=\sum \frac{1}{X} p(X)$